# Convert string between different charsets in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, character-encoding, nsstring, iconv

I'm newbie with Objective-C and Cocoa. But i develop simple mail client. And i have some problem with encoding.
MIME headers may look like this:

```
From: =?UTF-8?B?eWVsbA==?= <example@mail.com>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?0J/RgNC+0LLQtdGA0LrQsCDRgdCy0Y/Qt9C4?=
```

or like this:

```
Subject: =?KOI8-R?B?zc7F?=
From: user <example@mail.com>
```

or like this:

```
Subject: test subject
From: testname <example@mail.com>
```

So as you see, if it's not ASCII string, it's have following format:

```
=?{charset}?{B or Q}?{Base64 or Quoted-printable encoded string}?=
```

So after base64 decoding we know charset of this string.
Is there analog of PHP function [iconv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php), for example. Or how to make coversion between different charsets in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use these two NSString methods

```
- (BOOL)getBytes:(void *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)maxBufferCount usedLength:(NSUInteger *)usedBufferCount encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding options:(NSStringEncodingConversionOptions)options range:(NSRange)range remainingRange:(NSRangePointer)leftover

- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```